# Access global values

Tags: vba, variables, global

It is possible to use a variable from a ‘SelectionCange’ in a module?
I would like to use the variable NoOfCol in my module ‘Autofit’ – How can that be done?

See added fotos

[SelectionChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJQaN.png)
[Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3mJ9.png)

Comment: You define Globals in a module at the top (above subroutines), using `Global` instead of `Dim`. However, you should try to avoid global Vars. Why don't you pass the value as parameter? And please, don't post code as images.

Comment: `If Target.Value = "AutoFit" then AutoFit noOfCols` then `Sub AutoFit(noOfCols As long)`